# Prove that a simple connected graph has even numbers of vertex

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory, simple-functions

Given a simple connected graph G that all of its vertex degree is 3.
how can I prove that G has even number of vertex?
and does G has a perfect matching and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose for a contradiction that $G$ has odd number of vertices $n$ and $e$ edges. Then, by Handshaking Lemma we have $2e = 3n$ where $n$ is odd so $e = \frac{3n}{2}$ is not an integer, which is a contradiction as required. Therefore $G$ has even number of vertices.

But $G$ may not have a perfect matching as in this example:

[image]

Comment: Three-regular graphs do not necessarily have perfect matchings. I can post a counterexample when I get the time.

Comment: Oh, now that you mentioned it, I just found one. I will edit this post, thank you for pointing that out :)

Comment: I never knew there was a *Handshaking Lemma*. I was attempting to prove this via Hamiltonian paths haha

Comment: @user477343 Hamiltonian paths are HARD. They usually aren’t a helper tool unless the problem deals with larger spanning structures.

Comment: @BobKrueger Yes I see what you mean. There is a conjecture that if you get all the numbers from $1$ to a number $n > 89$ then there is a way to order each number in a sequence so that two adjacent numbers add up to a squared number. Last time I checked, namely four days ago, this has been verified for $n \leqslant 300$, so as far as I know, the conjecture has been extended for $n > 300$. This conjecture requires the use of Hamiltonian paths, so of course this remains as an open problem, and a hard one too haha :)